# how to set vector input of Tensorflow Lite C++

Tags: python, c++, tensorflow

I have a binary text classification model and I'm trying to test simple tensorflow lite c++ code with TensorflowLite model. The original model will convert the string input to a vector, and the model will take the vector as input and then make predictions. I have found some information online regarding setting up inputs for lite c+ code. But they mainly take single float or int value as inputs. I am not sure how I should set up vectors input for tensorflow lite c++ code

This is my code

```
// Build the interpreter
  tflite::ops::builtin::BuiltinOpResolver resolver;
  InterpreterBuilder builder(*model, resolver);
  std::unique_ptr<Interpreter> interpreter;
  builder(&interpreter);
  TFLITE_MINIMAL_CHECK(interpreter != nullptr);

  // Allocate tensor buffers.
  TFLITE_MINIMAL_CHECK(interpreter->AllocateTensors() == kTfLiteOk);
  printf("=== Pre-invoke Interpreter State ===\n");
  tflite::PrintInterpreterState(interpreter.get());

  // Fill input buffers
  // TODO(user): Insert code to fill input tensors
  int input = interpreter->inputs()[0];
  float* input_data_ptr = interpreter->typed_tensor<float>(input);
  // I created dumpy test data here
  std::vector<int> vec = {39, 22, 17, 28, 31, 22, 33, 12, 6, 3, 6, 2, 15, 27, 25};
  int size = static_cast<int>(vec.size());
 //My oirginal python model will do padding so the vector will be fixed as 128 dimensions
  while (size <128)
  {
         vec.insert(vec.begin(), 0);
         size++;
  }
  for (int c = 0; c <128 ; ++c) {
        *(input_data_ptr) = (float)vec[c];
        input_data_ptr++;

  }

  // Run inference
  TFLITE_MINIMAL_CHECK(interpreter->Invoke() == kTfLiteOk);
  printf("\n\n=== Post-invoke Interpreter State ===\n");
  tflite::PrintInterpreterState(interpreter.get());

  // Read output buffers
  // TODO(user): Insert getting data out code.
  int output_idx = interpreter->outputs()[0];
  float* output = interpreter->typed_tensor<float>(output_idx);
 printf("Prediction Result: %f\n", output);
  return 0;
```

This is the output message, the prediction results is always 0.0 no matter what test data I use

```
Node   0 Operator Builtin Code  53 CAST
  Inputs: 0
  Outputs: 33
Node   1 Operator Builtin Code  36 GATHER
  Inputs: 2 33
  Outputs: 34
Node   2 Operator Builtin Code  22 RESHAPE
  Inputs: 34 32
  Outputs: 35
Node   3 Operator Builtin Code 119 WHILE
  Inputs: 12 12 4 3 3 35 5 10 15 16 17 18 35 23 19 6 7 8 9 24 20 25 21 26 22 31 12 11 14 13
  Outputs: 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65
Node   4 Operator Builtin Code  77 SHAPE
  Inputs: 38
  Outputs: 66
Node   5 Operator Builtin Code  22 RESHAPE
  Inputs: 38 66
  Outputs: 67
Node   6 Operator Builtin Code  45 STRIDED_SLICE
  Inputs: 67 28 29 30
  Outputs: 68
Node   7 Operator Builtin Code   9 FULLY_CONNECTED
  Inputs: 68 27 1
  Outputs: 69
Node   8 Operator Builtin Code  14 LOGISTIC
  Inputs: 69
  Outputs: 70
Prediction Result: 0.000000
```